# Repurpose IR blaster LEDs

Tags: gpio, hardware, lirc

I'm currently using this single IR transmitter https://de.aliexpress.com/item/1922513322.html to send IR signals. It works but its quite limited in range. That's why I'd like to reuse only the IR LEDs from this old blaster.
[image: ir blaster]

The blaster has WiFi and some tuya software on it but I don't want any of that to be powered. I want my to only control those blaster IR lamps with a gpio of my raspberry.

Can someone please help me understand how to wire this? Any pointers would be helpful.

Edit: I think I found the wiring diagram for the blaster https://developer.tuya.com/en/docs/iot/universal-remote-control?id=Ka5hi8rwx02zs

Comment: How much do you know about critical timing in a Linux Operating System? Or calculating the current limiting IR LED resistors? Or how much current a RPi's GPIO can handle. And, finally, the wave form of most common IR controller protocols? Just the 1st question is likely to knock this project off its rails. The timing necessary to create the most commonly used IR wave form (some where around 40KHz) will be difficult while the processor is also busy running a Linux Operating System. That is why a dedicated embedded processor (an ESP in this case) is placed between the LED and most computers.

Comment: Nah man I got it working. I'm powering the blaster via microusb and I'm sending the signal output to IO14 on this W3BS chip. Pretty simple stuff and required none of the knowledge you're talking about.

Comment: But you said "I want my to only control those blaster IR lamps with a gpio of my raspberry.". You need most if not all that knowledge to do that.

Comment: Why though? The raspberry is running lirc and taking care of all the stuff you mentioned, then outputting the signal on one of its gpios. Now I just have to connect this ready-made IR signal with the IR LEDs of the blaster.

Comment: I'll be, you are correct. Most LIRC/RPi examples on the web do use a transistor to drive the IR LED.

Comment: (Just a side note, I wonder if the original range was bad because the power source was current limited? Most older USB ports are only obliged to support up to 500mA. That may not have driven all 7 IR LEDs at their full potential. I might try a USB power supply rated at several Amps before abandoning the original IR transmitter.)